# positioning span?

Tags: jquery, css

take a look at this validation demo:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

the error messages are placed on the right side to the fields.

i have wrapped span on my messages and want to place them to the left side of the input fields. how do i do that with css?

Comment: Do you want the input to move to the right when the validation is failed or do you just want more space between the label and the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want, you can hack the code on `jquery.validate.js` and look for this line:

```
label.insertAfter(element);
```

and change it to:

```
label.insertBefore(element);
```

Comment: tried that, that will push the input elements to the right, and that is not what i want. but a good hack though:)

Comment: I think you just need to css it... how about giving us some sample of the html... in a before and (should) after state of the desired output...

Comment: Why would you hack it when jquery.validate allows you to customize the error placement yourself?

Comment: I would not hack it if it's me cause I can css it... the problem is this guy is not giving much info... that's the best answer I could think of for him now...

Answer (score 1):

You just want to move them with CSS (that is, whithout changing where those elements occur in the HTML)?  One way would be: `position: relative; left: -120px; top:-20px` (or whatever values you find put them where you want.

Comment: To clarify, I was looking at the validation messages on the upper group of fields . . . the lower ones look like there wouldn't be room to the left without moving some other things around . . . you could do `float:left` to bring them all the way to the left of the line and push the other stuff over . . . or just insert the elements  in a different position to begin with (either in the HTML source for the page, or with JavaScript).

Comment: the problem is if i positioning them with pixels then longer error messages will cover the input fields while shorter error messages will be far from the input fields on the left side. they have to be right-positioned from the input fields. is that possible with css?

Comment: If you can change the HTML of the page (as opposed to just applying CSS), I would try putting the error message and the corresponding input field in a div, then applying `float: left` to the error message.  (If you don't contain it in a div, it will float all the way to the left of the line -- that is, even to the left of the "first name", "last name", etc. -- which I don't think is what you want.)